# Node Edges with Distribution

Tags: haskell, distributed-computing, actor, cloud-haskell

I've been playing around with cloud Haskell (erlang style distribution), and I was curious if there was any reason not to have every node store the node id of every other node.  I think it makes distributing the database easier as well as balancing processes, and the n size should be small enough that it shouldn't take up too much memory.  But before I move forward I was just curious if there are any downsides I haven't thought of.

Thanks